# Compiling with Ogre + MFC in _DEBUG mode

Tags: c++, mfc

There is a problem compiling Ogre with MFC in debug mode, you get an error because of the MFC macro:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
```

Which basically clobbers Ogre's debug new -

```
#define OGRE_NEW new (__FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__)
```

I'm trying to get MFC+Ogre to run merrily together in DEBUG mode, and I got it to compile with:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#undef new
#endif
Ogre::Root * root = OGRE_NEW Ogre::Root( pluginsFile, "ogre.cfg", "Ogre.log" );
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif
```

But now, I get a runtime error: Ogre::InternalErrorException

Anybody else face/solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might be a problem in the specific machine I was using.  I tried this out on another machine, and it seemed to work in debug mode with the #ifdefs #undefs as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to remove the MFC debug macro rather than the Ogre one. Check this article on the Ogre Wiki here titled [Common Mistakes Ogre Wiki](http://www.ogre3d.org/wiki/index.php/CommonMistakes)

Comment: hmm.  I know about this, but I was hoping to compile and run, allowing Ogre to use its memory allocation functions and MFC to use its own memory allocation functions

Comment: maybe i can try simulate the scenario you have and see what i get on my end